# Exporting and importing RSA keys

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

I have created an app that creates a signed XML file.
Microsoft has some straight forward examples it was not that difficult to implement but much is hidden/ encapsulated in the libraries below

System.Security.Cryptography
System.Xml,
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

I now need to export the public key and put it (the public key) in a second application so it can verify that the signed XML document is genuine.
My second application can then enable/disable various program features based on the contents of the signed XML file.
Microsoft goes on about not exporting the contents of the key container but that is exactly what I think I need to do because in my mind I need to accomplish a couple of things.
One as mentioned above I need to export the public key and then import it into a key container that resides in the application that uses the signed XML file.
Secondly I think I need to export both private and public keys in order to back them up.
Since my application will be distributed with the public key I need to back up the public, the private key and the hashing algorithm in a safe location. 
 
Microsoft goes on about not exporting keys to clear text but I am uneasy/and don't know how to back up the key container and I'm unsure how to look at the thing and know what I want to store is actually in there when I try to view the key container in the debugger it seems to go on forever (some sections appear to repeat recursively??)
Can anyone offer advice on how to export/import RSA keys to a key container and an approach to backing up mykeys or contaner?.

Answer (score 0):

Open the [Microsoft Management Console](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console) (mmc.exe), navigate to `File` -> `Add/Remove Snap-in`
This dialog will pop up

[image: MMC Snap-in Dialog]

On the `Available snap-ins` pick "Certificates"; click `Add` and choose to add `My user account`, then click `Add` again and choose `Computer account`.

Click `OK`. Now you find any certificates you'll need and functions to import/export them - both private (if available and exportable), and public.

Comment: Hi esskar
Thnaks for the reply.

Comment: Above should say "Thanks for the reply" the five minute timer is annoying as heck! I will check that out today as soon as I stomp out a couple of fires. I found this article on MSDN called Walkthrough: Creating a Cryptographic Application [link](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-5792/ms.help?method=page&id=ABF48C11-1E72-431D-9562-39CF23E1A8FF&product=VS&productversion=100&locale=en-US&topiclocale=EN-US&topicversion=100&SQM=2)

Comment: Hi Esskar
After a long delay I'm finally back to this task.
I had assumed (maybe incorrectly) that because I had created my RSA keys programmatically I would want to import & export all my certs programmatically.

Comment: After thinking about it a while it makes sense that I would be able/want to import and export my RSA keys via the certmanager snap in for my own education and so it will be in a convenient file format to back up the keys but I would also want to do it programmatically so the user is not required to install a cert as part of the installation so the user will have the public key.

Comment: Here is the code that creates the RSA encryption keys.
          <code>  cspParams = new CspParameters();
            // Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "MY_RSA_KEY";
            rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

Comment: The code does work to encrypt a signature of my xml file because I can test it i.e. if I make any change to the file it will fail to decrypt the signature.
I also know that the key persists because I can compile and run the program and encrypt the xml file on one day and decrypt the signature on another day it will still work.
So I believe that the constructor RSACryptoServiceProvider if passed a name that already exists in this example "MY_RSA_KEY" will use the existing key and not create a new one each time the program is run.

Comment: If I use the certmanager to export the file what format should I choose?
If I have multiple certs how do I tell them apart if the name I used to create them is nowhere to be found?................... (at least by me) 
I am also working on understandingout how to export and import the certs programmatically, if you have any guidance there I would be thrilled to hear about that as well.

Comment: I wish I could figure out how to post my code maintain the formatting